# How to access System Settings when Ubuntu menu is broken?

Tags: system-settings

I've seen this bug a number of times on several installations, but as yet I'm not sure how to reproduce it. Basically the System Settings item on the "gear" menu stops working. It's not grayed out or anything. It just ignores my click or Enter key. Any clue how to work around this, like how to launch it from the command line or how to actually fix this problem?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1322418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue so i tried this and work: open the terminal an insert: 
unity-control-center

this will open the default ubuntu control center if it is intalled, if not i will give you the instructions to install it, just follow them and the system settings will appear after this

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Have a look at the bug report linked above. It has something to do with removing Bluetooth Transfer. If you reinstall Bluetooth Transfer, then the System Settings menu suddenly works again.